# download latest bzr revision only

Tags: bazaar

Sometimes I want to get a bzr branch (e.g. `lp:~elementary-design/+junk/elementarywalls` or `lp:gimp`), but I have a slow Internet connection and only want to download the latest revision. How do I do this, starting with an empty folder (i.e. no pre-existing branch on my computer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
bzr checkout --lightweight lp:~elementary-design/+junk/elementarywalls
```

From the help entry:

> --lightweight         Perform a lightweight checkout.  Lightweight checkouts
>                           depend on access to the branch for every operation.
>                           Normal checkouts can perform common operations like
>                           diff and status without such access, and also support
>                           local commits.